# c++, Display the records in data base which are having same date

Tags: c++

I need to display the records which are having specific date. Please check "void display_fromDate". I'm receiving error "expected primary expression before char" and pointing the "int main() --> case 2. Appreciate your advise.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;



class patient
{
    int contactnum;
    char name[50];
    //float add;
    char bookingDate[15];
    char bookingTime[5];
    char trtType[15];
    //int add, bookingDate, bookingTime;
    //double per;
    //char grade;
    //void calculate(); 
public:
    void getdata();     
    void showdata() const;  
    void show_tabular() const;
    int getIDNum() const;
    char bDate() const;
}; 


/*void patient::calculate()
{
    per=(physics+chemistry+mathematics+english+comscience)/5.0;
    if(per>=90)
        grade='A+';
    else if(per>=80)
        grade='A';
    else if(per>=75)
        grade='A-';
    else if(per>=70)
        grade='B+';
    else if(per>=65)
        grade='B';
    else if(per>=60)
        grade='B-';
    else if(per>=55)
        grade='C+';
    else if(per>=50)
        grade='C';
    else
        grade='F';
}*/

void patient::getdata()
{
    cout<<"\nEnter The Contact Number of the Patient ";
    cin>>contactnum;
    cout<<"\n\nEnter Patient's Name: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(name,50);   
    cout<<"\nEnter Booking Date: ";
    cin>>bookingDate;
    cout<<"\nEnter Booking Time: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin>>bookingTime;
    cout<<"\nEnter Treatment Type: ";
    cin>>trtType;
    //calculate();
}

void patient::showdata() const
{
    cout<<"\nContact Number: "<<contactnum;
    cout<<"\nName: "<<name;
    cout<<"\nBooking Date: "<<bookingDate;
    cout<<"\nBooking Time: "<<bookingTime;
    cout<<"\nTreatment Type: "<<trtType;

}

void patient::show_tabular() const
{
    cout<<contactnum<<setw(6)<<" "<<name<<setw(4)<<bookingDate<<setw(4)<<bookingTime<<setw(4)<<trtType<<endl;
}

int  patient::getIDNum() const
{
    return contactnum;
}



void Savepatient(); 
void displayAll();  
void Searchdisplay(int);    
void modifypatient(int);    
void deletepatient(int);    
void DisplayClassResult();  
void DisplayResult();           





void write_patient()
{
    patient st;
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("patient.dat",ios::binary|ios::app);
    st.getdata();
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&st), sizeof(patient));
    outFile.close();
    cout<<"\n\nPatient record has been Created ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}



/*void display_all()
{
    patient st;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("patient.dat",ios::binary);
    if(!inFile)
    {
        cout<<"File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
        return;
    }
    cout<<"\n\n\n\t\tDISPLAY ALL RECORD !!!\n\n";
    while(inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&st), sizeof(patient)))
    {
        st.showdata();
        cout<<"\n\n====================================\n";
    }
    inFile.close();
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}*/

void display_fromDate(char n)
{
    patient st;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("patient.dat",ios::binary);
    if(!inFile)
    {
        cout<<"File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
        return;
    }
    bool flag=false;
    while(inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&st), sizeof(patient)))
    {
        if(st.bDate()==n)
        {
             st.showdata();
             flag=true;
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
    if(flag==false)
        cout<<"\n\nrecord not exist...";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}





void display_sp(int n)
{
    patient st;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("patient.dat",ios::binary);
    if(!inFile)
    {
        cout<<"File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
        return;
    }
    bool flag=false;
    while(inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&st), sizeof(patient)))
    {
        if(st.getIDNum()==n)
        {
             st.showdata();
             flag=true;
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
    if(flag==false)
        cout<<"\n\nrecord not exist...";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}


void modify_patient(int n)
{
    bool found=false;
    patient st;
    fstream File;
    File.open("patient.dat",ios::binary|ios::in|ios::out);
    if(!File)
    {
        cout<<"File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
        return;
    }
        while(!File.eof() && found==false)
    {

        File.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&st), sizeof(patient));
        if(st.getIDNum()==n)
        {
            st.showdata();
            cout<<"\n\nPlease Enter The New Details of Patient"<<endl;
            st.getdata();
                int pos=(-1)*static_cast<int>(sizeof(st));
                File.seekp(pos,ios::cur);
                File.write(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&st), sizeof(patient));
                cout<<"\n\n\t Record Updated";
                found=true;
        }
    }
    File.close();
    if(found==false)
        cout<<"\n\n Record Not Found ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}



void delete_patient(int n)
{
    patient st;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("patient.dat",ios::binary);
    if(!inFile)
    {
        cout<<"File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
        return;
    }
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("Temp.dat",ios::out);
    inFile.seekg(0,ios::beg);
    while(inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&st), sizeof(patient)))
    {
        if(st.getIDNum()!=n)
        {
            outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&st), sizeof(patient));
        }
    }
    outFile.close();
    inFile.close();
    remove("patient.dat");
    rename("Temp.dat","patient.dat");
    cout<<"\n\n\tRecord Deleted ..";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}


void class_result()
{
    patient st;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("patient.dat",ios::binary);
    if(!inFile)
    {
        cout<<"File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
        return;
    }
    cout<<"\n\n\t\tALL PATIENTS BOOKING DETAILS\n\n";
    cout<<"==============================================================\n";
    cout<<"Mobile.No      Name                Booking Date   Booking Time"<<endl;
    cout<<"==============================================================\n";
    while(inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&st), sizeof(patient)))
    {
        st.show_tabular();
    }
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    inFile.close();
}




int main()
{
    char ch;
    int num;
    cout.setf(ios::fixed|ios::showpoint);
    cout<<setprecision(2); 
    do
    {
    system("cls");
    cout<<"\t@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@";
    cout<<"\n\n\t1.CREATE PATIENT RECORD";
    cout<<"\n\n\t2.DISPLAY ALL PATIENTS RECORDS";
    cout<<"\n\n\t3.SEARCH PATIENT RECORD ";
    cout<<"\n\n\t4.MODIFY PATIENT RECORD";
    cout<<"\n\n\t5.DELETE PATIENT RECORD";
    cout<<"\n\n\t6.DISPLAY CLASS RESULT";
    cout<<"\n\n\t7.EXIT";
    cout<<"\n\n\t@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@";
    cout<<"\n\n\tPlease Enter Your Choice (1-7): ";
    cin>>ch;
    system("cls");
    switch(ch)
    {
    case '1':   write_patient(); break;
    case '2':   display_fromDate(char n); break;
    case '3':   cout<<"\n\n\tPlease Enter Patient's Contact Number: "; cin>>num;
                display_sp(num); break;
    case '4':   cout<<"\n\n\tPlease Enter Patient's Contact Number: "; cin>>num;
            modify_patient(num);break;
    case '5':   cout<<"\n\n\tPlease Enter Patient's Contact Number: "; cin>>num;
            delete_patient(num);break;
    case '6' :  class_result(); break;
    case '7':   exit(0);;
    default:    cout<<"\a"; 

    }
    }while(ch!='7');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Advice: create separate structures for Time and Date.  Don't store as arrays or text.  Separate structures will make comparison, input and output easier.

Comment: Advice: don't use `char []` for text.  Use `std::string` instead.

Comment: BTW, patients don't need to be calculated, nor do they have grades.  I suggest removing the code and not commenting.

Comment: If possible, could you please change it as you mentioned. I tried but not working for me. I'm just new and editing a old code to match the requirement. Appreciate if you can ....

Comment: Take a step back first, and study the posting guidelines. Apart from the requirement for you to post a minimal (!) example, they also explain a few things you can do to solve your problem yourself.

Comment: What do you expect `case '2':   display_fromDate(char n); break;` to do, especially the `char n`?

Comment: I'm need get all the records entered by specific date. case 2 was gave me the search option and presented the record which match to contact number. But I'm not able to edit it correctly. Please assist

Answer (score 0):

This may not solve your issue, but it can help.
*(To Downvoters: this is too big to fit in a comment.  Also, please leave comment when downvoting.)*

Some foundation:

```
struct Time
{
  unsigned int hours;
  unsigned int minutes;
  unsigned int seconds;
};
struct Date
{
  unsigned int day;
  unsigned int month;
  unsigned int year;
};
```

With the time and date structures established, the patient structure now looks like:

```
class Patient
{
  public:
  unsigned int  contact_num;
  std::string   name;
  std::string   trtype;
  Date          booking_date;
  Time          booking_time;
};
```

To make the date comparable, you could add a few methods:

```
bool  operator==(const Date& d)
{
  return (year == d.year) && (month == d.month) && (day == d.day);
}
bool  operator< (const Date& d)
{
  if (year == d.year)
  {
    if (month == d.month)
    {
      return day < d.day;
    }
    else
    {
      return month < d.month;
    }
  }
  return year < d.year;
}
```

With that you can write some *ordering* (comparison) functions for your Patients:

```
bool Order_By_Date(const Patient& p1, const Patient& p2)
{
  return p1.booking_date < p2.booking_date;
}
```

If you had a vector of `Patient`, you could order (sort) them by booking date by using:

```
std::vector<Patient> database;
//...
std::sort(database.begin(), database.end(), Order_By_Date);
```

The concepts can apply equally to the `Time` structure and the booking time.

Advanced sorting functions, such as by name then by date, are left as an exercise for the OP.

### Edit 1: Searching or finding by date

The STL search *algorithms* can be used with an ordering or comparison function, similar to the `std::sort` function above.

To [find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) a person by date:

```
static Date  search_key = 
{
  .year = 2016;
  .month = 01;
  .day   = 22;
};

bool Find_By_Date(const Person& p)
{
  return p.booking_date == search_key;
}

std::vector<patients>::iterator iter =
  std::find(database.begin(), database.end(),
            search_key,
            Find_By_Date);
if (iter != database.end())
{
  cout << "Person found: " << iter->name << "\n";
}
```

I recommend reviewing other `std` search functions, such as `lower_bound`.

If none of those are adequate, you can always write your own.